# how do I get python 3.2 to take the whole number (even if it's zero) and get rid of the decimal

Tags: python, required

I'm trying to make a program that will convert minutes to hours

What I have is this:

```
print("This program converts minutes to hours")
mi = float(input("Enter the total minutes: "))
hr = round(mi/60,)
mic = round(mi%60,)
print(hr)
print(mic)
```

it works fine when I insert anything over 60 minutes, but I want it to work with things under 60. Please help me.

Comment: `hr = mi // 60` should work

Answer (score 1):

you could simply do

```
hr,mi = divmod(mi,60)
```

alternatively you could force integer division with

```
hr = mi // 60
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate hours and minutes and get rid of the decimal, mapping round with divmod can be used. For example, with Python 3:

```
In [26]: mi = 29.58

In [27]: hr,mic = tuple(map(round,divmod(mi,60)))

In [29]: print(hr, mic)
0 30

In [30]: mi = 100.21

In [31]: hr,mic = tuple(map(round,divmod(mi,60)))

In [32]: print(hr, mic)
1 40
```